# AWS EKS EFS-CSI Driver version and how to upgrade it

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

With lots of known issues[1][2] in EFS-CSI driver, i'm planning to do this driver upgrade on a running cluster.

I read most of AWS documentations but couldn't get any straight forward answers for following questions.

1. How to view current efs-csi driver version in EKS cluster.
2. How to upgrade the efs-csi driver to a specific version in a running cluster.

[1] https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/issues/616

[2] https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/issues/673

Answer (score 0):

If you already have installed efs-csi drivers and used Helm to install efs-csi drivers, upgrade is so straightforward. Regarding to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html):

```
helm upgrade -i aws-efs-csi-driver aws-efs-csi-driver/aws-efs-csi-driver \
    --namespace kube-system \
    --set image.repository=602401143452.dkr.ecr.region-code.amazonaws.com/eks/aws-efs-csi-driver \
    --set controller.serviceAccount.create=false \
    --set controller.serviceAccount.name=efs-csi-controller-sa
```

Regards